# Gelfand Kirillov dimension and associated graded algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, associated-graded

Given a filtered module $M$ over a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, can one describe the Gelfand Kirillov dimension of $M$ in terms of Gelfand Kirillov dimension of its associated graded $grM$? If so, under what conditions are they equal to each other?